# How does multisorting work in php7 with an array containing mixed datatypes?

Tags: php

So I wrote the following code:

```
$a= array( array("10", 11,100, 100, ),
       array(1,2,"2", 3,));

array_multisort($a[1],SORT_ASC, SORT_STRING);
```

My sorted array is :

```
"10", 11, 100, 100
1 , "2", 2 ,3
```

On what basis is the mixed sorting happening?